# Nginx's configuration

Tags: linux, web-services, url, nginx

I am sorry for my poor English.
But I couldn't found any useful information with my mother's language :(

I am running a Nginx server on my VPS.
And I wanna access /home/username/public_html/
with URL like "http://example.com/~username/"

Now I use

```
ln -s /home/username/public_html/ /var/www/html/~username
```

To access my directory.
But when I try to use "Rewrite"
I found I don't known how to code this.
I have been try this code in nginx.conf

```
Location / {
     root /var/www/html;
    rewrite ^~(.*)/$ /home/$1/public_html break;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

your rewrite must point to an url, for ex :

```
rewrite  (.*)  http://www.example.org ;
```

see exemple here : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html